# Nested Jasmine Spies on SpyObj

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a constructor that receives a spyObj called TestService:

```
constructor(private testService: TestService) {
    testService.getTestData().subscribe((settings) => {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Using Jasmine, how can I create spies for subscribe() and getTestData() on TestService?

Thanks in advance!
Mike